# Why does powershell collect uncaptured values and returns it as an array

Tags: powershell, return

The following code, although I would think should return a single value, returns an array.

```
function Do-Something {
    123
    return 456
}

(Do-Something).GetType() # will say Object[]
```

I learned that if I want to avoid this I have to pipe the unwanted values to Out-Null like so

```
function Do-Something {
    123 | Out-Null
    return 456
}
```

However, I couldn't find any reasoning behind why PowerShell is implemented this way. I find that this can lead to nasty and silent bugs if you forget that something has a return value that you did not capture. Could someone explain when this could come in handy? Also is it possible to force powershell not to collect all uncaptured variables in an array?

Comment: If you're not doing something with an output, it is output to stdout (the console, pipeline, whatever you want to refer to it as)

Comment: ___"I find that this can lead to nasty and silent bugs if you forget that something has a return value that you did not capture."___ Could you give an example? I can't think of a command that gives an output when you don't expect it.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 I get that but I still don't understand why you would want to include it in the return value of the function (that you expect to return a single value).

Comment: Because `return` is a control construct in powershell more than it is a way to say "return this object".  @Paxz I was initially surprised `New-Item` had a return object while `New-ItemProperty` does not.

Comment: @Paxz what happened to me today is I somehow deleted Write-Host before a console message which screwed up things in the caller function that called toString on the return value which was now Object[] instead of what I intended to return

Comment: The behaviour is [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_return), so it shouldn't be surprising.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I read that page. It's not that it's surprising. I'm saying it's easy to mess up and I don't see the inherent value in this way of returning values. E.g. ArrayList.Add() returns the number of elements before the addition. If you forget to capture this (which seems quite easy), it ends up in your return value. Why would I want that? I'd just like to know the reasoning behind going about it this way, which I couln't find in the documentation.

Comment: First off, to a certain extent barring having Snover pop in here, pretty much any answer you get will most likely be opinion and speculation. Personally, I think the reason is that it fits with the pipeline concept.

Comment: In contrary to `I don't see the inherent value in this way of returning values.` I find it quite handy to just have to fill a ´[PScustomObject]` and have it returned without further ado. But this gets OT as it's `primarily opinion-based`

Comment: I don't think this question is opinion based. OP asks why the behavior is experienced, and for its justification. Sure, whether or not we should be using `return` would be an opinion-based answer, or asking "when is this useful?" Perhaps OP could remove the additional questions that may generate opinion based answers from the question body, but the base question, IMO, is valid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PowerShell emits the output of all statements in a script or function into the output pipe because it's a shell and that's how shells work. The `return` statement is somewhat regrettable in that functions don't return objects, they write objects into the pipeline. Being able to terminate the execution of a function is necessary but we probably should have called it something else. The ability to simply emit objects makes simple scripts simpler because there is no need for explicit output statements or returns. Does it sometimes cause problems - yes, sometimes it does. Consequently, for classes, as introduced in V5, we went with more traditional programming language semantics. If a method in a class is going to return something, it *must* declare a return type and it *must* use the `return` statement to return a value, otherwise nothing will be returned.

Answer (score 2):

Anything written to the output stream is considered part of the pipeline - `return` is a bit of a misnomer in Powershell. While it *does* "return" a value, anything else previously written to the output stream is also part of the "returned value". In Powershell, use `return` to "write to the pipeline and exit the current function". It's more like what `break` is to a loop than what a traditional `return` directive is to a function or method.

If you want to output `123` but not as part of the pipeline, consider using [`Write-Verbose`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-verbose?view=powershell-6), [`Write-Warning`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-warning?view=powershell-6), [`Write-Debug`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-debug?view=powershell-6), or [`Write-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-host?view=powershell-6) (this would be an appropriate use of `Write-Host` since you do *not* want the output to be considered as part of the pipeline).

As for *why* it works this way, it works like this in most other shell languages, and should be expected. Any `STDOUT` output in a `cmd`, `sh`, or `bash` for example can be stored in a variable, piped to another command, or otherwise redirected. While Powershell is a powerful scripting language, it is still also an interactive shell, and behaves as such.

Though you are not alone in thinking that `return` is confusing considering its implied meaning based on most other programming languages.

Comment: Quibble: PowerShell's stdout (standard output) _equivalent_ is called the _success [output] stream_ - see [`Get-Help about_Redirection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection)

Comment: Fixed above. So would `Write-Host` write to `STDOUT`? Or is the output stream and `STDOUT` the same thing, just named differently in Powershell?

Comment: Loosely speaking, `Write-Host` writes directly to the host, where _host_ is PowerShell's generalization of the terminal/console concept - any environment that hosts PowerShell. The console host prints to the console, though if you invoke PowerShell via its CLI from the _outside_ (e.g., `cmd.exe`, `bash`), `Write-Host` output too goes to that outside world's _stdout_. Note that since v5 `Write-Host` targets the host via the newly introduced information output stream, `6`.

Comment: 123 was an oversimplified example. I should have added something more subtle and easier to miss like the example I mentioned above in the comments: you add an element to an ArrayList and forget to capture its return value, now your function returns an array instead of the string the caller expects. Anyway, good explanation, thanks. I like Bruce's answer slightly more so I'm marking that as the accepted answer but I'm also upvoting yours.

Comment: I mean, you can't get much better info than from a founding member of the Powershell team :P. And he offered some good info on when `return` needs to be used in the context of classes, something I haven't messed around with yet in Powershell (though I'm very familiar with how .NET classes work).